# Using appcache in Meteor app

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, meteor, html5-appcache

I have enabled `appcache` (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/appcache) in my Meteor app.

But the server console says that the total size of my cached resources is 10.2MB.

From the doc, I see that I have to exclude some files since they are too large with

```
Meteor.AppCache.config({
  onlineOnly: [
    '/bigimage.jpg',
    '/largedata.json'
  ]
});
```

The problem is that I don't know which files are too large. I keep my files splitted as good as I can, and since the stylesheets and javascript files are minified, I don't think they use much resource.

I do not have any images or other special files in my app at all. It is pure js and html (even no css).

## Edit

I tried checking `chrome://appcache-internals/` from which I got following details

```
http://localhost:3000/
Manifest: http://localhost:3000/app.manifest
Size: 10.3 MB
Creation Time: Thu Oct 22 2015 08:51:07 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)
Last Access Time: Thu Oct 22 2015 10:16:37 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)
Last Update Time: Thu Oct 22 2015 10:16:36 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)
Remove Item View Details
```

When I click `View Details`, I get a long list of files being cached.

These javascript files are larger than 1MB:

```
http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?019cba9c67d18d17c34ea48a455d8956ded05487 1.1 MB Explicit
http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_tabular.js?b5a33bda4b2c2ddbf08d97504162570faea3b826 1.9 MB Explicit
http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?1015953f785c9b76503e2ecb391507dce965f357 1.2 MB Explicit
```

but they are all external libraries, so I don't know what to do with them. Shouldn't all the JS files be minified?

I have

```
standard-minifiers          # JS/CSS minifiers run for production mode
```

in my `packages`; however, I'm not sure if they are unminified on localhost but minified when uploading to a server?

Comment: I have no experience with Meteor's appCache, but have you tried visiting your site in Chrome and looking at `chrome://appcache-internals/` (just put that as a URL in a new tab)? It should list all resources cached locally, so it can help you figure out if anything is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question

Comment: Well, 1MB libraries aren't unheard of I suppose, again I have no experience with meteor so I don't know if this is how it's supposed to be. You probably want to check for duplicate entries though, as the `?`-parameter is considered part of the URL by appcache, it will cache `my_url?1` separate from `my_url?2`. you could try look for duplicates manually by using ctrl-f on some files

Comment: @Jamgreen where I can add this:
Meteor.AppCache.config({
  onlineOnly: [
    '/bigimage.jpg',
    '/largedata.json'
  ]
}); ?

Answer (score 1):

Meteor send down all those client javascript and css files (including those from third party packages) in development mode, which ends up taking lots of space, hence the misleading warning from the appcache package.

But in production mode, and better yet with the deployment build, those get concatenated, minified and gzipped.

So in order to truly know what your client size cache will become, you should do a `meteor build` and check the actual production file sizes.

You'll be happily surprized to see that it is just a fraction of what you get on your development version.

Beware of the static assets such as images, though!

Comment: Instead of `meteor build` you can use `meteor run --production` to quickly check how your app would look like in production

Comment: @Minderov `meteor build` and `meteor run --production` are quite different and the latter lacks *lots* of optimizations that the former provides. So results may be misleading, to say the least.